# Striped table in CSS

Tags: html, css, email, templates, html-table

I am using base.html for css styling and another html template for table. I want to add style in base.html so that I can reuse base.html for striped table. I have tried nth-child but it did not work and I don't want to make that styling in home.html. I doubt if it has to do with for loop in home.html. Is there a way to make striped table styling in base.html? This is for email template. This code works fine when running on browser but when used to send an email, it does not apply the styling i need.

**base.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
        <style type="text/css">
            table tr td{
                color:black;
                background: white;
                border: 1px;
            }
            th{
                color:black;
                background: white;

            }
            table tr:nth-child(2n+1) td{
                background: orange;
            }
            table.collapsed{
                border-collapse: collapse;
                border:1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="pretty">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<table align="center" summary="output">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">
            Column A
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            Column B
        </th>
        <th scope="col">
            Column C
        </th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in data[1] %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{row[1]}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{row[2]}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{row[3]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
        {%endfor%}

</table>

{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As unpleasant as this sounds, if you're sending the html as an email it looks as though you're going to have to hard code the background color in a style element on each row. The [caniemail.com](https://www.caniemail.com) resource is quite handy to check if your html or css is supported.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `:nth-child(odd)` and `nth-child(even)` to style the rows.
You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

I have created a small example to illustrate what i mean

```css
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Knocky</td>
    <td>Flor</td>
    <td>Ella</td>
    <td>Juan</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Breed</td>
    <td>Jack Russell</td>
    <td>Poodle</td>
    <td>Streetdog</td>
    <td>Cocker Spaniel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Owner</td>
    <td>Mother-in-law</td>
    <td>Me</td>
    <td>Me</td>
    <td>Sister-in-law</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eating Habits</td>
    <td>Eats everyone's leftovers</td>
    <td>Nibbles at food</td>
    <td>Hearty eater</td>
    <td>Will eat till he explodes</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i have tried that and it did not work

Comment: :nth-child isn't very well supported on emails I'm afraid https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-pseudo-class-nth-child/